# Is it possible to completely obfuscate javascript used in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have some sensitive Javascript in a Chrome Extension that I do not want to be visible to clients. Is it possible to secure this code through obfuscation. I am not looking to 'put a few obstacles' in the way, I am looking for 100% complete security where whoever is using the Chrome Extension has no way of understanding the Javascript.

Because if not, all it takes is one person to unobfuscate the code and I would have a disaster on my hands. So, is this possible?

Comment: [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is never a correct anwser.

Comment: "Is it possible to completely obfuscate javascript used in a Chrome Extension?" - No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible!

Every bit of code which runs on a machine can be unobfuscated, even *.exe files! Due to using JavaScript, this is much more simplier.

You should move the sensitive part of your application to an external resource (e.g. a server). Never put sensitive logic in the client!

Answer (score 2):

### No.

Even for programs written in something like ***Assembly*** there isn't `"100% complete security"`. You can go more native to make it harder, using the NPAPI, but there isn't a way of getting 100% security.

Comment: +1 for mentioning NPAPI! That's definitely more secure than any JavaScript code.

Comment: @ComFreek - well, NPAPI may allow better obscurity by linking to native code, but it doesn't meet the 100% secure bar the OP asked for either.  A determined hacker can reverse engineer native code too.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah, as I said, there isn't a way of getting 100% security. Native code only helps make it more obscure than JavaScript. That isn't close to a 100%

Comment: @jfriend00 I have not said that. But it is more obscure than JS (byte code) for sure. If you don't even trust native code, whom do you trust else?

Answer (score 0):

> Because if not, all it takes is one person to unobfuscate the code and I would have a disaster on my hands.

Then find another solution. There is no 100% complete security in obfuscation. Obfuscation can slow down reverse engineering, but it can not prevent it. When your code is understandable for the javascript engine of the browser, it is also understandable for a sufficiently determined human.

When you would describe what you want to hide, why you need it and why you need to hide it, we could maybe come up with a better solution.

Answer (score -2):

**No**, you cannot secure client javascript, ever.  Obfuscation is just a minor obstacle for a determined hacker.  It is not security in any manner of the word and it's not even close to the "100% complete security" that you asked for.  You simply cannot get that type of security with client-based code, particularly client-based javascript code.

If you want your algorithm or implementation secure so the code cannot be seen, then you must implement that part of the code on a server somewhere that you can secure and control access to the code on.  Your extension on the client can then ask the server to carry out tasks for it using the secured code.

Comment: -1 for me-too answer which doesn't add anything not said before by someone else.

Comment: @Philipp - The advice in my second paragraph is not contained in your answer at all.  I wouldn't have written an answer (why waste my time) if there was a single answer already that contained all the parts that I thought were relevant with a clear explanation.  There was not so I provided one.  Using your logic, it is unclear to me what your answer adds that Amaan's answer doesn't already have.

Comment: That information is in the post by ComFreak, and the three answers were posted in the same minute, so they didn't know about each other.

Comment: I can understand people posting an answer one or two minutes after others with the same contents because they were writing them **at the same time**. But posting it one hour after the others **with** the same content, that's just redundant. @Philipp is right except that ComFreek is written with two *e*s ;)

Comment: Jeez people.  A good answer has both all the relevant information and a good clear explanation of it.  I still see no other answers that meet that criteria.  A good answer does not have to come in the first 5 minutes after the question is asked and the best answer may indeed be a combination of things that have been said before, but combined and presented in a single answer that has not yet been done.  Why don't you people spend your energy improving your own answers rather than raining on mine.  You have an edit button - you can use it.

Comment: As I saw the landscape when I provided my answer, there were three answers that said "no" it isn't good security and one that mentioned moving something to a server, but none that put it all together in a decent and clear explanation.  Sorry, I tried to provide an answer that didn't leave out things and explained clearer.  What's wrong with that?  Isn't that to the benefit of SO and to the OP?